# Make row in listview clickable/selectable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, row, multiple-columns

I have a listview with four columns. I would like the entire row to be selected if someone clicks on one of the elements in the row. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably only need this:

```
ListView1.FullRowSelect = True
```

Comment: Thanks. this works. Didnt see this setting in the properties.